# Can 8thWall Web ( i.e. 8thWall integrated in amazon sumerian application for Browser) do marker based tracking or marker recognition successfully?

Tags: 8thwall-web

I am looking to create a WebAR app which recognizes custom image markers and show content augmented on top of them, have looked in to "blippar" and "zappar" both of which are a no go because of pricing.

8th Wall and amazon sumerian combo seems the best solution forward, but since 8th wall has multiple solutions for platforms. none of the documentation is satisfying enough to clarify if what i want to achieve is possible using it for the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, After actually developing the application using 8th Wall and sumerian, Here is my answer to the feasibility of this option-

Yes, 8thWall provides proper marker based WebAR solution for amazon sumerian, They have a very active slack channel which you should join, It contains code snippets to primary issues faced by users in the chat history.